# Compile time error when declaring variables in C inside control section

Tags: c, gcc, syntax, c99

I am trying to compile a program (Listing 12.13 - manydice.c from Stephen Prata's C Primer Plus 6th Edition) but am getting a compile error: 'status' undeclared (first use in this function).

I'd be grateful also for clarifications about the c99 standard of "declaring anywhere".

Here is part of the code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int dice, roll;
    int sides;

    srand((unsigned int) time(0));       /* randomize seed       */
    printf("Enter the number of sides per die, 0 to stop.\n");
    while(scanf("%d", &sides) == 1 && sides > 0)
    {
        printf("How many dice?\n");
        if((status = scanf("%d", &dice)) != 1)
        {
            if(status == EOF)
            {
                break;                  /* exit loop            */
            }
            ...
```

The error message is:

```
||=== Build: Debug in dice (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
~manydice.c||In function 'main':|
~manydice.c|19|error: 'status' undeclared (first use in this function)|
~manydice.c|19|note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Options: (Using code::blocks 16.01 mingw 32bit --gcc version shows gcc 4.9.2, Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit)

```
 mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g -std=c99  -c
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Because you *haven't* defined the variable `status` that you are using.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that even looks like an attempt to declare `status`. Where did you think it was being declared?

Comment: @ Wumpus Q. Wumbley Like I said am learning, am learning this example from the said book (I entered exactly as in the book) and it won't compile and I don't know what's wrong so I put up this question. It would have helped better if you explain the mistake to me rather than pointing out more mistakes I've no idea about

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)` should not work. `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` is the proper alternative.

Comment: For reference, [the book's published code](https://github.com/szaydel/c-primer-plus-book-6ed/blob/master/Ch12/manydice.c) is quite a bit different.

Comment: @red_speck, you've made a positive assertion via your question title that the usage you present conforms to C99.  Do not, therefore, fall back to "I'm just a newbie" when challenged on the accuracy of your assertion.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Thanks for pointing out. (The book version didn't contain 'int status;' declaration.)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Now I've learned a little more. And thanks @JohnBollinger for your kickass comment. (Well I better rephrase my question a bit I guess)

Comment: The relevant features add by C99 are (a) declarations and statements may be mixed within a block (C90 requires all declarations to precede all statements), and (b) the first clause of a `for (;;)` statement can include a declaration. (Note that both C90 and C99 permit declarations in nested blocks; the C90 restriction is on ordering within a block. A block, even one that contains declarations, is a statement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, you claim that variable declarations are permitted in C "control sections", among which you apparently include the condition of an `if` statement.  You are mistaken.  From C99, a declaration is permitted in place of the first expression in the control clause of a `for` loop, but ***not*** in place of the controlling expressions in other flow-control structures, such as `if` or `while` statements.

In the second place, "declaration" is not synonymous with "first appearance".  A declaration of an identifier associates at least type information with that identifier, and its placement establishes the identifier's scope.  If there is *no* declaration -- as in your case -- then there is *no* scope in which the identifier may be used.  Primordial C had looser rules about that, but inasmuch as you seem to want to rely on C99, those are irrelevant.

The simplest possible declaration for your variable `status` would be this:

```
int status;
```

That would need to appear before the first use of that variable, and its scope extends to the end of the innermost enclosing block, or to the end of the file if it appears outside any block.  In your case, however, I would probably just replace

> ```
>         if((status = scanf("%d", &dice)) != 1)
> ```

with

```
         int status = scanf("%d", &dice);

         if (status != 1)
```

That both declares `status` and computes an initial value for it, which you then use.  I find that clearer than performing the value computation and test in the same expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation (or understanding) is wrong.

Quoting chapter §6.8.4.1, `C11`, the syntax for the `if` statement is

> `if (` *expression* `)` *statement*

and, a variable *declaration* is **not** an *expresssion statement*.

You can, however, have a variable defined in the *statement* part.